# How do I stop a website for overriding my keyboard short cuts

Tags: firefox, youtube, browser-plugin

How can I stop websites from overriding the keyboard shortcuts in Firefox?

e.g., if you go to Youtube, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> no longer opens a new tab, etc.

It there a plug-in that will do that for me?

Comment: On YouTube, this is indeed caused by the Flash plugin. But in general, keyboard shortcuts can also be overwritten with javascript, see http://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox/670040#670040

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a focus issue....when you click on the flash player, focus is transferred from the browser window to the flash plugin.

This is a page on IBM's website with describes a method of creating a firefox extension that prevents hotkeys from being captured by flash [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-78414-firefox-flash/index.html)

Unfortunately, I'm unsure how effective this solution will be. I've seen on various forums people saying that there is no real way to prevent a plugin from grabbing the keyboard completely because of how mozilla handles plugins, and I haven't been inconvenienced enough to try to use the code I mentioned above.

It looks like the most convenient workaround would be MicTech's solution of clicking anywhere except the animation, and then proceeding with the shortcuts.

Comment: In this case, I notice that if I click outside of the video frame then my keyboard short cuts work again. An extra click will solve my problem for now. Thanks.

Comment: This behaviour might be changing soon: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78414

Answer (score 3):

I think, this is problem with Flash.

If you click on video player on youtube, then short-cuts stop working, but if you click outside video player, then short-cuts start working.

I have same problem, too.

Answer (score 3):

The focus- and Flash-related answers are legitimate, and may help some people, but don't address the overall question raised by the subject: How to prevent sites from hijacking keyboard shortcuts. And the asker mentioned Firefox specifically.

Well, 11 years after the bug was filed, Mozilla has finally taken action on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380637, which directly addresses this issue.

In current versions of Firefox (starting with v.58; I'm using v.59) there is a new per-site preference, but unfortunately it's problematic (as discussed in recent comments on the bug ticket): It prevents the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> keys from working in the browser itself (e.g. to edit entered text), which is likely to be a deal-breaker for most people.

But you can experiment with the current implementation (and hopefully, access a fixed version in Firefox 60) by clicking the `(i)` icon in the Location Bar (or by pressing Ctrl-I, presuming you're on a site that hasn't hijacked that shortcut), going to the `Permissions` tab, and adjusting the Override Keyboard Shortcuts` setting:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't a flash issue as mentioned by MicTech, then it may be a JavaScript issue. I use NoScript, which disables JavaScript on a whitelist basis, so you can allow sites to use JavaScript if you a) trust them and b) require the javascript functionality while there.

Comment: +! - I've used that trick before. But some sites is use do require JS. Now, if I can find something that will selectively block the JS hotkey interceptors as well.