# How to stop websites from disabling firefox keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to forbid keyboard shortcut stealing by websites in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox)

How to stop websites from disabling firefox keyboard shortcuts?
i notice my most used sites such as ecwid.com, YouTube and many other modern Web 3.0 sites are disabling the ctrl+t shortcut to open a new tab in. It seems to be something to do with ajax script and their wishing to force us to use mouse actions ton track our page surf movements. However, the new tab shortcut is something i use 10000 times a day, and wish to block such sites from being able to disable my keyboard shortcuts. using about:config, is there a way to adjust or solve this bothersome aspect of web 3.0? why have KB shortcuts if the websites disable them??

Comment: Same question asked here. http://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox