# Chrome: Modify webapp keyboard shortcut

Tags: mac, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, jira

Jira has a [keyboard shortcut](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/ViewKeyboardShortcuts!default.jspa) of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for form submit on Chrome Mac. It's awkward. Is there a way to change this locally? I am not the Jira admin.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in Jira without third-party software for keyboard remapping, etc.

There was a suggestion/improvement submitted for [custom keyboard shortcuts in Jira](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-33365), but it was resolved as "No Fix" by the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

The website is using javascript to watch for specific key combinations. You could create a user script using the TamperMonkey addon to intercept their interception and cancel it.

Somebody asked a similar question and the answer provided an example user script to accomplish this. Their example uses GreaseMonkey in firefox but Tampermonkey should serve the same purpose in Chrome.

[How to forbid keyboard shortcut stealing by websites in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox)