# How do I prevent pages I visit from overriding selected Firefox shortcut keys?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, javascript, hotkeys

In Firefox, how can I prevent pages from overriding Firefox built-in keyboard shortcuts through Javascript on a per-key basis? Preferably on a per-site basis, too? The most frustrating override is the forward slash ('/') that's linked to "Find in page". Sites like Google search results, Twitter timelines, some wikis, and other pages steal the slash key for their own search boxes, which is completely wrong.

*Since my rep lets me ask, edit, and answer questions, but not add comments, this is basically a duplicate of these other two questions that weren't properly answered:*

[How do a stop a website for overriding my keyboard short cuts](https://superuser.com/questions/8764/how-do-a-stop-a-website-for-overriding-my-keyboard-short-cuts)

[Firefox: don't allow websites to override the / (slash) key](https://superuser.com/questions/113806/firefox-dont-allow-websites-to-override-the-slash-key)

Comment: I get frustrated with PHPMyAdmin overriding ctrl-<left arrow>... it's a good question

Comment: I can't stand websites that override default behaviour. A lot do it with middle-clicks as well. See [this related question](http://superuser.com/questions/468960/restore-my-browsers-middle-click-behaviour/489224) for a solution to that problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forbid keyboard shortcut stealing by websites in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/168087/how-to-forbid-keyboard-shortcut-stealing-by-websites-in-firefox)

Comment: I've answered over here: https://superuser.com/a/1688490/21402

Answer (score 19):

Building on edymtt's answer, I've created a userscript which disables only specific keyboard shortcuts. You can add more shortcuts to disable by adding [keycodes](https://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm) to the keycodes array, or restrict which sites to apply it to by replacing the `@include` tag with one or more patterns.

Install using [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable keyboard shortcuts
// @description    Stop websites from hijacking keyboard shortcuts
//
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        *
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

keycodes = [191] // Keycode for '/', add more keycodes to disable other key captures

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
//    alert(e.keyCode); //uncomment to find out the keycode for any given key
    if (keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1)
    {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Almost complete solution for meta keys, too--- I was trying to keep Google Docs from intercepting Previous-tab (Cmd+Left) and Next-tab (Cmd+Right) and found that I also needed to set useCapture to true; i.e., document.addEventListener('keydown', yourHandlerFn, true)

Comment: note that the value `191` depends on your keyboard layout, as far as my azerty setup is concerned (I have 16 + 58 for the alpha area and 111 for the numpad)

Comment: and unfortunately doesn't to work anymore nowadays (tested on phabricator and twitter). custom listener is triggered but site's event is triggered anyway and 'search in page' doesn't show up.

Comment: @sylvainulg I see that it doesn’t work on Twitter, but at least it works on GitHub still. I wonder what changed.

Comment: This works everywhere I tried it except php.net. I wonder what event they are using.

Comment: You can find the keycodes here https://keycode.info/

Comment: Perfect, I used this to stop github hijacking ctrl+f etc. (Keycode 17)

Answer (score 19):

Since Firefox 58 it is possible to disable keyboard shortcuts override per web site.

"Override Keyboard Shortcuts" and many other permissions are available in "Page Info -> Permissions" (under info icon in URL bar).

[image: Firefox Permissions example for superuser.com]

[Keyboard override was introduced in Firefox #380637](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380637)

Comment: Yes, after 11 years they finally did a half-assed job of fixing that ticket. Unfortunately the current implementation (still in FF 59) completely disables the `Backspace` and `Delete` keys, which really sucks.

Comment: Also, unfortunately it doesn't prevent web pages from capturing non-shifted (i.e., no `Ctrl`, `Shift` or `Alt` key) input--which means this doesn't help at all with the slash key mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Lambart - good to know, I ended up not using this too, since firefox keyboard shortcuts became fixed in jira and confluence (somewhere around firefox 59)

Comment: what was fixed? JIRA and Confluence both still grab all sorts of keys that constantly disrupt my workflow. I see this as Atlassian's problem: They need to allow people to disable (and/or change) their "shortcuts".

Comment: firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1433592 fixed atlassian products for me (there might have been atlassian fixes in same timeframe)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Interesting, but I hadn't experienced that issue.

Comment: Did this support vanish in the last few years? I can't see this setting. :(

Comment: Ok. The shortcut in the top bar was gone. To reach this panel you now need to press Ctrl-i. Unfortunately this doesn't get back Ctrl+e (end-of-line) on github.com. I still get their annoying "wrap in backticks" shortcut.

Answer (score 8):

With regard to Google and the Quick Find shortcut, you can install this Greasemonkey script:

http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/132237

As the description says, it "stops google from focusing the search input on every key press" -- in particular, if you press `/` with the keyboard focus outside the search box the Quick Find will appear, as it will on other web sites.

I have only installed it without touching the code, but I think it could be easily adapted to work with other sites and/or other shortcuts.

Comment: To clarify: this userscript stops ALL keyboard shortcuts on pages which it is enabled for, preserving the browser's own functionality. To apply it to other websites just add more @include tags.

Comment: without any information about what is hiding behind the link, the answer is unfortunately useless when userscripts-mirror.org gets down, blocked by a firewall or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general script - you can define any number of keypress events to disable.

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5819-disable-website-keyboard-hooks

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable website keyboard hooks
// @description    Stop websites from hijacking keyboard shortcuts.
// @author         Isaac Levy
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        *
// @grant          none
// @version        0.0.1
// @namespace      https://isaacrlevy.com
// ==/UserScript==

var keycodes = [ // Add keycodes as desired, keep sorted.
    37, 38, 39, 40 // Arrow keys.
]

var meta_keycodes = [ // Disable these when meta key is pressed.
    70
];

// Don't change below this line.

var isMac = navigator.platform.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') >= 0;

// Create a fast lookup.
// This saves work during normal typing. Maybe unnecessary.
var keycode_offset = keycodes[0];
var keycode_arr = Array(keycodes[keycodes.length - 1] - keycode_offset)
for (var i = 0, len = keycodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    keycode_arr[keycodes[i] - keycode_offset] = true;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    if ((isMac && e.metaKey) || (!isMac && e.ctrlKey)) {
        if (meta_keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    } else if (keycode_arr[e.keyCode - keycode_offset]) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry - but I cant get this to work. Especially I want to disable the arrow keys left and right on a site - but with this script the arrow keys still control the site???