# Restore my browser's middle-click behaviour

Tags: javascript, browser

Some sites do annoying things with JavaScript, like replace the default behaviour of the browser to open a new tab on middle click, with code such as:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"
 onclick="window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'; return false;">
 Stack Overflow</a>
```

Is there any way I can give control back to my browser so that I'm the one that decides when a new tab gets opened or not? Right now I have to resort to either right clicking on the link and selecting *Open link in new tab*, or middle clicking on my browser's *Back* button after being rudely navigated away.

Comment: so you want to change what `window.location.href` does?

Comment: I don't see how the code you show would specifically open links in a new tab unless your browser is configured to do so. What browser are you using?

Comment: Disable JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated which browser you're using, but I found [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/middle-button-new-tab/ikbkhpkapkmhaoiabhlkmicpeakhhpip) for Chrome. I haven't tested it extensively, but it works for twitter.com, which by default pops up a little profile box when middle-clicking on someone's twitter handle, rather than open their full profile in a new tab.

Comment: Just installed that extension and it works!

Comment: That links now 404s