# Disable github focus search bar shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, github

As is described in [Github - keyboard shortcuts](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/keyboard-shortcuts#site-wide-shortcuts), <kbd>s</kbd> is a shortcut for focusing the search bar. Is it possible to disable that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With modification of [this](https://superuser.com/a/595885/1115289) comment

Install Grease Monkey (FF) and use this script

```
// Your code here...

// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable keyboard shortcuts
// @description    Stop websites from highjacking keyboard shortcuts
//
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        *github.com*
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

keycodes = [83] // Keycode for 'S', add more keycodes to disable other key captures

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
//    alert(e.keyCode); //uncomment to find out the keycode for any given key
    if (keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1)
    {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Or Download TamperMonkey (Chrome) and use this script

```
// Your code here...

// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable keyboard shortcuts
// @description    Stop websites from highjacking keyboard shortcuts
//
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        *github.com*
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==



document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

     if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    return false;
});
```